# Abscissa of convergence of the $\tau$ Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions, dirichlet-series

Define the $\tau$ Dirichlet series $L$ by
$$L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\tau (n)}{n^s}$$
where $\tau$ is defined by
$$q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau (n)q^n$$
where $|q|\lt 1$.

According to Wolfram (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RamanujanTauL.html), the Dirichlet series for $L(s)$ converges for $\Re (s)\gt 6$. According to Chandrasekharan's *Elliptic Functions* (p. 140), it converges for $\Re (s)\gt 13/2$.

I'm confused. What is the abscissa of convergence of that Dirichlet series? Is it $6$, $13/2$ or smaller? Or is it possible that we know that it converges for $\Re (s)\gt 13/2$ but don't know if it converges for smaller $\Re (s)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the sum
$$S(x):=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\tau(n)}{n^{11/2}}.$$
By Theorem 1.3 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I, the abscissa of convergence equals
$$\sigma_c=\frac{11}{2}+\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log|S(x)|}{\log x}.$$
The value of the $\limsup$ here is not known, but it is known to lie between $1/4$ and $1/3$; probably $1/4$ is the truth. So $\sigma_c\in[23/4,35/6]$.

**Added.** The upper bound follows from the results of Walfisz (1933) and Deligne (1974). The lower bound follows from the results of Redmond (1979) and Murty (1983).